# Toggle two PHP files using jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two PHP files one called cab.php and another called d3.php , I want to toggle

in the same file this works cab.php
the problem is when I call the second file d3.php

```
function botaod2mostraesconde()
{
       $(".wrapd2").toggle();
       $(".datad2").toggle();
       $(".uploadd2").toggle();
}
```

here 
the input button :

```
<input type="button" value="D3" onclick="location.href = 'd3.php'">
```

I am looking for a way to toggle from different files. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run the JavaScript on the next page (d3.php). You can't execute client side script (JavaScript) on a php page that runs server side which hasn't yet been loaded in the client's browser.

This is based on an edict written in stone eons ago:

**Thou shalt not execute client side code before server side code.**

This would be akin to Luke attempting to destroy the Death Star before it's been created.  Wait for the Death Star, you must.  Then use The Force to destroy it.

Run d3.php first, then toggle elements on the page using JavaScript.